# IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. AchMenu.setAchievs () (at Assets/Scripts/AchMenu.cs:63)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2D game for android, Unity 2020.3.30f1.When I try to start the game I get an error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>
> AchMenu.setAchievs () (at Assets/Scripts/AchMenu.cs:63)
>
> AchMenu.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/AchMenu.cs:29)

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class AchMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int money;
    public int total_money;
    [SerializeField] bool isFirst;

    public string[] arrayTitles;
    public Sprite[] arraySprites;
    public GameObject button;
    public GameObject content;

    private List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
    private VerticalLayoutGroup _group;
    void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money");
        total_money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("total_money");
        isFirst = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isFirst") == 1 ? true : false;

        RectTransform rectT = content.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectT.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        _group = GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>();
        setAchievs();

        if (isFirst)
        {
            StartCoroutine(IdleFarm());
        }
    }

    private void RemovedList()
    {
        foreach (var elem in list)
        {
            Destroy(elem);
        }
        list.Clear();
    }


    void setAchievs()
    {
        RectTransform rectT = content.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectT.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        RemovedList();
        if (arrayTitles.Length > 0)
        {
            var pr1 = Instantiate(button, transform);
            var h = pr1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height;
            var tr = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            tr.sizeDelta = new Vector2(tr.rect.width, h * arrayTitles.Length);
            Destroy(pr1);
            for (var i = 0; 1 < arrayTitles.Length; i++)
            {
                var pr = Instantiate(button, transform);
                pr.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = arrayTitles[1];
                pr.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].sprite = arraySprites[i];
                var i1 = 1;
                pr.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => GetAchievement(i1));
                list.Add(pr);
            }
        }
    }

    void GetAchievement(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 0:
                Debug.Log(id);
                break;
            case 1:
                Debug.Log(id);
                money += 10;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
                break;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IdleFarm()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        money++;
        Debug.Log(money);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
        StartCoroutine(IdleFarm());
    }

     public void ToMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

What I can do?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a **Typo**:

```
                |
                V
for (var i = 0; 1 < arrayTitles.Length; i++)
```

... As soon as you have at least 2 elements `1` will **always** be smaller then the `arrayTitles.Length`! You wanted an `i` here.

Note that you did the same also here

```
                                                     |
                                                     V
pr.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = arrayTitles[1];
```

---

However, in general you iterate over the

```
arrayTitles.Length
```

but access

```
arraySprites[i];
```

there is no guarantee that `arrayTitles` and `arraySprites` actually have the same amount of items.

In general instead of two independent lose collections I would rather have a proper class to bundle the information

```
public class TitleInfo
{
    public string Title;
    public Sprite Sprite;
}
```

and then rather have one single collection

```
public TitleInfo[] titleInfos;
```

and now you can safely iterate and access

```
for(var i = 0; i < titleInfos.Length; i++)
{
    var titleInfo = titleInfos[i];

    ...
}
```